# How to add a class via jquery to posts that are visible inside the viewport on page load and to the posts that come into viewport on scroll?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I'm making a WordPress blog and I'm trying to create an animation effect for the posts when they come into viewport, but I'm trying to do this without using any javascripts plugins.
On my front page the first post takes the 100% width of the container, while every subsequent post takes 50% so that 2 posts can fit next to each other inside the container.

the first post has 3 relevant classes by default: 'post', 'featured' and 'animated', while every subsequent post has a default class 'post'.
I added the 'animated' class to the first post by default in order to trigger the animation immediately after the page loads, while for every subsequent post the class 'animated' is added via jquery after the post comes into viewport.

to do this I'm using this piece of jquery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    var offset = 50;

    // Recalc height of window in case of resize
    $(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
        winHeight = $(window).height();
    });

    // When we scroll we do some checks...
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {

        // get current scrollPos
        var trigger = $(window).scrollTop() + winHeight;

        // Rip through elements we're affecting
        $('article.post:not(.animated)').each(function() {
            var elementOffset = $(this).offset().top;

            if( elementOffset < trigger ) {
                $(this).addClass('animated');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

To create a CSS animation I made this piece of CSS code:

```
article.post {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: matrix3d(0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    transition: opacity 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s, transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s;
}
article.post.animated {
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: matrix3d(0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        transition: opacity 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s, transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 1) 0s;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    }
}
```

The problem I have is when I go to the archives page, all the posts are 50% width by default and the 4 of them are immediately visible inside the viewport, but since I don't add the class animated to them through php, the class animated is added to them only after I scroll down, so when the page loads, they are not visible nor animated before I scroll because the class article.post has opacity set to 0.
How do I edit the jquery code above in order to take into account posts that are visible inside the viewport on page load and add the class 'animated to them right away instead on page scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attaching your scroll event to window, you can just run it:

```
$(window).trigger('scroll');
```